# I am trying to update a table on postgreSQL 9.6 and pg admin 4 and it is not updating/inserting

Tags: sql, dml, postgresql-9.6

I am trying to update a table on postgreSQL 9.6 and pg admin 4 and it is not updating/inserting. Basically no write query is working, although it is working on that tab but when I open new tab try to see my changes, the changes are not there and data is same.

Simple sql query like update name or insert row,
issue is not with SQL query.

Comment: Please [edit] your question add the sql statements you are using. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: simple sql query like update name or insert row not an issue with SQL query.

Comment: If pgAdmin supports transactions (I don't know), it could be that you have to commit your statements before you see any effect.  If that doesn't help try psql (the commandline tool) instead of pgAdmin, and/or inspect the PostgreSQL log files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pgAdmin go to File -> Preferences -> SQL Editor.  You probably have AutoCommit set to off.  Either turn it on or add a "COMMIT" statement in order to see the effect in other tabs.

Answer (score 0):

In my case my seeing in file--> prefereneces-->Query Tool ---> Options[image]